# What should I do if I lost my Indian passport when I am traveling?

Tags: visas, passports, lost-documents

My friend was in Frankfurt, Germany when he lost his passport and contacted me. The German business visa was of course in it. I actually had no idea what to do in such situations. Although he found the passport later, but i would like to know should a person do under such situation. This answer may differ for different countries, but i would like to know as an Indian citizen travelling to some other country.

Comment: I guess, you don't really need the Visa once you have got in to Germany.  Of course, to get a new PASSPORT, you simply contact the Indian Embassy, in Germany.  ie, the Indian Embassy is the thing that your country (India) owns in Germany.  You need only google "indian Embassy in Germany" to find it: https://www.indianembassy.de  As you can see it is in Berlin.  You'd simply phone them and they'd tell you what to do about a lost passport.

Comment: Then you have the issue of getting the GERMAN paperwork again. Exactly as Henning explains very elegantly below, the Indian people at the Indian Embassy - will of course know exactly how to do this: they will tell you what to do.  (Since they do it every day!) Again, you can probably just "not bother" replacing the German visa if, say, you are not coming again.  Or, just wait until you get back to India and replace it at your leisure (if you're coming again).

Comment: @JoeBlow: The Schengen policy is that a visa is not only required when _entering_ the area but is also documentation of your right to _stay_ in the area, and the exit immigration when you leave is supposed to check that you complied with the visa conditions. So I wouldn't assume as blithely that lacking the visa is unproblematic for a traveler in this situation.

Comment: A quick google search leads to [indian embassy, germany](https://www.indianembassy.de/pages.php?id=30) and they have all info (point 3)

Comment: @HenningMakholm "the exit immigration when you leave is supposed to check that you complied with the visa conditions" That's actually optional for them to do. So he *might* get away with it

Comment: hi @HenningMakholm by all means you have to be aware of the fine print.  But what is the chance of a visa being checked *while you are there?*, maybe that happens to one visitor in ten million?  sure, keep in mind the accurate view but you have to have a picture of the "real world" view with visa issues!

Answer (score 5):

Generic answer:

The experts in dealing with this situation are **your country's consulate in the foreign country**. (If your country has an *embassy* in the host country, the embassy will usually also act as a consulate, but this is not always true -- be sure to research it in advance. Even if your country has an embassy they may *also* have consulates that are closer to where you find yourself, particularly in large countries).

Before you leave home, look up the contact details for the relevant consulate(s) and keep them with you, in several different places such that you're unlikely to lose all of them to pickpockets or burglars.

The consulate will be able to arrange for an emergency passport so you can return home. They will usually recommend (and often require) that you go to the host country's police and report the theft of the original passport. Since dealing with these situations is one of the core purposes of a consulate, they will also have the practical experience to know which local bureaucracy is involved in dealing with the loss of the visa.

Comment: Side note: If you are an EU citizen (which the original poster isn't), any EU embassy or consulate can help you if there is none of your own country.